# How to use log.io logging module in Node.js

Tags: node.js, logging

In my node application i want to use log.io logging module to store my application log messages.Now i have installed that module using this docs.https://github.com/NarrativeScience/Log.io
Now i dont know which method in log.io have to call to store my log.

This is my app file.

```
 var express=require('express');
 var app=express();
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
 app.listen(9090);
 var logger = require('log.io');
 logger.whichMethodToLogMsg('my error msg');
```

Comment: provide more information about your problem, exactly how are we supposed to guess or know, what "my app" is?

try reading the log.io documentation, i'm pretty sure that it provides this kind of information

Answer (score 0):

I have misunderstood the log.io concept.Log.io module look for changes in log files.If there any change in that file means it will send the logs to the server.Then socket.io will display the logs in the web UI.I have tried the example given in their documentation(http://logio.org/). Now im able to see my application logs in web UI.